# How to group just part of a dataset in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, grouping

Say I have a table in SSRS with 3 columns. For example like this, where the first row is the header and second row is the data:

```
--------------------------------------------
| PersonID  |  PersonName  |  AmountWorked |
------------------------------------------
| PersonID  |  PersonName  |  AmountWorked |
--------------------------------------------
```

What I need is to add a column group to this dataset, **but only** to the AmountWorked column. Is there a way to do this? The field on which this grouping would occur is coming from the same dataset. Everything involved is from the same dataset.

Every time I try Visual Studio applies the column grouping to all the columns, not just to the one at the end. I want the grouping applied only to the end column.

Is there a way to do this?

**UPDATE**

I'd like the final result to look like this, where the AmountWorked is group to department:

```
                                  AmountWorked 
---------------------------------------------------     
| PersonID      PersonName      Dept1   Dept2   Dept3
| 1             Bob             2       9       2
| 2             Jack            4       5       4
| 3             Sue             56      0       8
| 4             Bill            3       3       0 
| 5             Jane            3       2       5
| 6             Cindy           6       7       33
```

Comment: Could you add an example of how you would like it to look after you have done this?

Comment: @Chris Latta, I've added an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a tablix to your report. Hook up the `Dataset` property to your dataset.

Right-click the `Detail` row handle and add a row group based on the person and tick to have a group header. You can now delete the `Detail` row. Right-click where the sum of amount worked will go and add a Column Parent Group on the department with the intersection cell having the expression:

```
=Sum(Fields!AmountWorked.Value)
```

If you have a Matrix as an option in your Toolbox then this is a good place to start as the Matrix is set up to do this type of table where the columns expand automatically.